# Extract domain names from multiple email addresses in Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split

I am trying to extract multiple domain names from the following data frame:

```
    email
0   test1@gmail1.com; test1@gmail2.com
1   test3@gmail3.com; test4@gmail4.com
2   test5@gmail5.com
```

I can split and extract the first email address using the following code:

```
orig = []
mylist = []
for i in df['email']:
    orig.append(i)
    i = i[ i.find("@") : ]
    i = i.split(";")
    i = ';'.join(i)
    mylist.append(i)
```

After appending the lists to a data frame I get the following result:

```
    origemail                           newemail
0   test1@gmail1.com; test1@gmail2.com  @gmail1.com; test1@gmail2.com
1   test3@gmail3.com; test4@gmail4.com  @gmail3.com; test4@gmail4.com
2   test5@gmail5.com  @gmail5.com
```

The result I am after:
(these email addresses may not be limited to two, it could be more.)

```
    origemail                           newemail
0   test1@gmail1.com; test1@gmail2.com  @gmail1.com; @gmail2.com
1   test3@gmail3.com; test4@gmail4.com  @gmail3.com; @gmail4.com
2   test5@gmail5.com                    @gmail5.com
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction to achieve the desired output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
orig = []
mylist = []
for i in df['email']:
    orig.append(i)
    emails = i.strip().split(';')
    domains = [x[x.find('@'):] for x in emails]
    if len(domains) == 1:
        domain_string = domains
    else:
        domain_string = '; '.join(domains)
    mylist.append(domain_string)
```

It (1) loops through all the emails, (2) appends them first to `orig`, (3) finds the domains, then (4) concatenates them and appends them to `mylist`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot for the quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop of your code need to be refactor like so:

1. append the current item to the original list
2. split all emails by semi-colon ';'
3. trim white space for each email
4. find the '@' sign and extract the substring of the domain
5. join all domains with ';'
6. append the result to mylist

Hope this seudocode can help.